# RTL8821CE wifi driver - can't connect after suspend or change network on Ubuntu 18.04 (Kernel 4.15)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, suspend

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 in a HP notebook. I downloaded the driver using:

```
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce.git
```

I followed the instructions in the README file for the installation.

The driver worked well after a computer reboot, but if I try to change wireless network or if the computer goes to suspension, network-manager can no longer connect. Network manager sees the ssid of Wi-fi in the air but fails to make the connection. In short, it only works on the first connection.

I've tried restarting network manager, and uninstalling and reinstalling it, but the problem persists. The only solution is restarting Ubuntu, and it is very annoying for me.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT2: rtl8821ce driver will be included in kernel 5.9 probably, meanwhile you can try https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88. I've been using it for a while now and it doesn't seem to have these issues. The driver is still new so expect bugs.

> **EDIT: Fresh install of ubuntu 18.10 (uefi) solves the problem permanently, you don't need to follow the below steps, just install ubuntu 18.10 and build the wifi module. It then should work flawlessly. There are, maybe, some bugs in ubuntu 18.04 LTS version which had been fixed in version 18.10**

**The main issue is that the wifi driver installed by dkms does not reload itself after suspend for some unknown reason.**

**I HAVE RTL8821CE AS MY WIFI CHIP SO MY KERNEL MODULE IS NAMED AS** `8821ce`

Open terminal login as `root` by issuing command `sudo -s` then issue the following commands (you may also use `sudo` instead of logging in as `root`)

`modprobe -r 8821ce` and

`modprobe -i 8821ce`

these commands will reload the wifi modules and your wifi will work again after suspend.

**I found a temporary workaround so as to avoid issuing those commands every time you resume from suspend.**

NOTE:

1. THIS WORKAROUND SOMETIMES WORKS AND SOMETIMES DOES NOT WORK
2. THIS MIGHT BREAK YOUR SUSPEND/RESUME BUT YOU CAN SIMPLY REVERT TO PREVIOUS STATE BY DISABLING THE SERVICE AND DELETING FILES.

The steps are;

1. Create a script that issues the above commands at resume (not at suspend) by

`sudo nano /etc/pm/sleep.d 20_anyname.sh` (replace anyname with anything of your choice)

and enter the following lines in the script

```
#!/bin/sh

# This script Restarts rtl8821ce kernel modules
# Use this if your wifi not working after suspend/resume

case "${1}" in
        resume|thaw)
               sudo modprobe -r 8821ce
               sudo modprobe -i 8821ce
;;
esac
```

then press *CTRL+X* and save changes by entering `yes`

Make sure that proper permissions are granted by

`sudo chown root:root /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_anyname.sh`

`sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_anyname.sh`

2. Create a systemd service by

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/somename.service`

Enter the following text

```
[Unit]
Description=Wifi Resume Service
After=sleep.target
After=hibernate.target
After=hybrid-sleep.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/path/to/your/script

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
WantedBy=hibernate.target
WantedBy=hybrid-sleep.target
```

and save by *CTRL+X* then type `yes` then enter.

Then make sure proper permissions are granted by

`sudo chown root:root /etc/systemd/system/somename.service`

`sudo chmod 755 /etc/systemd/system/somename.service`

3. Enable your script using
   `sudo systemctl enable somename`
4. Reboot and enjoy

AS I SAID BEFORE IT SOMETIMES WORK AND SOMETIMES NOT. I really don't know why is that so. To get a fully working wifi you need to wait for developers to put the bug free module in upcoming kernels as rtl8821ce is still a new chip.

First enable your local wifi network then suspend your laptop. Now to tell whether the script succeeded or not see the top right corner just after resume if you don't see any kind of wifi sign then you are good to go and if you see a wifi sign at first sight then script failed.

To see errors `journctl -u somename.service`

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue on a Lenovo Ideapad330. Same wireless chipset, and same problem when resuming after a suspend.

When reading the [readme for the 8821ce driver on GitHub](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce), tomaspinho talk about possible issues, especially "PCIe Activate State Power Management".

I have followed his recommendations, and I have added the following parameter to the grub cmdline

```
pci=noaer
```

Now I have no more wireless problem after suspend.

Comment: Which laptop do you have? I tried it but no luck. I doubt that this is bug in ubuntu 18.04 because other versions that I tested - 17.04 , 14.04 LTS, and 18.10 did not have any issues with the wifi driver. If `pci=noaer` worked for you, it means there is bug in bios itself, or maybe it differs for different oems.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a pavilion, and the accepted answer don't work to me, What i did was the following:

In ubuntu 18.04, create the script:

```
sudo vim /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wifi.sh
```

and copy and paste the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "Going to $2..."
    # Place your pre suspend commands here, or `exit 0` if no pre suspend action required
    ;;
  post/*)
    echo "Waking up from $2..."
    # Place your post suspend (resume) commands here, or `exit 0` if no post suspend action required
    modprobe -r 8821ce && modprobe -i 8821ce
    ;;
esac
```

Then give him user permissions:

```
sudo chmod a + x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wifi.sh
```

Ready.